# Input group icon inside file upload button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the input group to be a file upload button with an icon inside. I have tried the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>File</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">+</button>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <i class="input-group-btn fa fa-picture-o">
            <input type="file" class="btn btn-secondary" />
        </i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

without success... Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QErokkb0SB6ykI7dy5p5?p=preview). What I would like is a button like the one on the left but with an icon inside and the file upload function.

Please note that I need it working on Bootstrap 4

Comment: This isn't possible without a JS replacement for `<input type="file">`.  CSS is limited in what it can and cannot change on that input type.

Comment: @RobertC It is not correct, I can do it with bootstrap 3

Comment: Might want to read up on how Bootstrap 4 handles it's own baked-in custom file browser: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#file-browser

Comment: @RobertC Thanks, I got it working!

Comment: If you opted not to use V4s own custom file-browser you should post your own solution in the answer box to ensure future visitors can find a solution.

Comment: @RobertC Please see my answer... it worked for v4 as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded by adding the following css:

```
.btn-file {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 999px;
    text-align: right;
    opacity: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
```

and structuring my html:

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>File</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">+</button>
        </span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-btn"><span class="btn btn-secondary btn-file"><span class="fa fa-picture-o"></span>
          <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif"/></span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

See [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jUlhUnttWFDLRXMB7SjU?p=preview)